# Disney INFINITY: Marvel Super Heroes (2.0 Edition)

Tags: disney-infinity

If I buy the Disney INFINITY: Marvel Super Heroes (2.0 Edition) Xbox One Edition can you use the portal for Infinity 3.0 on PC and use 3.0 figures?

Answer (score 1):

The portal for Disney Infinity doesn't work with the PC.  Instead, if you buy characters at stores, they come with a little card that unlocks that character in-game.  You can also just buy some of the packs for the PC version as DLC outright.